# Deploying standalone Java application on LAN

Tags: lan

I've developed a simple java application using eclipse, I've already converted my codes to a .jar file and again converted my .jar file to .exe file. My program will allow a user to encode data(number of customers per day) and can call/read those data (per day), if i run my program, data encode is save to the same folder where my .exe file is located .  My question is, how can i implement my java application on to our local area network?  Where in a user can encode data from one of our computer station(part of our local area network) but save the data to our server hard disk and not to the station's hard disk, and also call/read those data using also the server's hard disk where those data should be saved. I don't intend to deploy it to the web I only intend to deploy my application to our Local area network, can this be done? I'm not experience with local area networking.  Please some help.